# how to have leading dots to page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to mimic the leading dots to be similar to
[image: Example TOC]

My current version looks like this
[image: Current TOC]

This is my code

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% used to fix the spacing in the LoT and LoF
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoF
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoT
\makeatother


\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 


\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS} 
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{LIST OF SYMBOLS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF SYMBOLS}

\chapter*{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}



\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

\end{document}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A revision and extension of your MWE.

```
% tocdotsprob.tex  SE 634639

\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% used to fix the spacing in the LoT and LoF
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoF
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoT
\makeatother
\end{comment}

%% as described in the tocloft manual to fix the spacing
\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}

% reduce space between dots
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{3.3}

% left align page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftpnumalign}{l}

\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 


\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS} 
\tableofcontents

%%%% originally SYMBOLS and ABBREVIATIONS overwrote each other

\chapter*{LIST OF SYMBOLS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{%\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
  LIST OF SYMBOLS}

\chapter*{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{%\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
  LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}

%% added
\listoffigures


%% most of the rest is added
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{Alpha}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  AN ILLUSTRATION
  \caption{Illustration}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  A GRAPHIC
  \caption{Graphic}
\end{figure}

\chapter{FIRST}
\section{Beta}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  AN ILLUSTRATION
  \caption{Illustration}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  A GRAPHIC
  \caption{Graphic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To me it was not clear from your question whether you wanted less spacing between the dots of the dots ending closer to the page numbers. I think that I have dealt with both of these, and also eliminating chapter spacing in the LoF and LoT, all via the `tocloft` package.

The page numbers are normally right justified in a box of a given width and the dots end before that box. I have made the page numbers left justified so the dotted lines end closer to the page numbers.

Please read the `tocloft` manual for more information.